# Adding new comboboxes Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with Swing interface on java. Explaination: I have a Combobox with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 items. When an exact item is selected I need to create some more comboboxes the number of which depends on the selected item. So, if number 5 is selected, 5 more comboboxes must appear in the frame. I used ActionListener but it did not work properly. However, the same code but outside Actionlistener works well. What a problem can it be?

```
public class FrameClass extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel;
    JComboBox box;

    String[] s = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    String[] s1 = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    public FrameClass() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        box = new JComboBox(s);
        JComboBox adults = new JComboBox(s);
        JComboBox children = new JComboBox(s1);

        panel.add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i <= box.getSelectedIndex(); i++) {
                panel.add(adults, BorderLayout.WEST);
                panel.add(children, BorderLayout.WEST);
            }
        }
        });
        add(panel);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new FrameClass();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: All the same with SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: add a call to `panel.revalidate();` after adding the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you don't inform the layout manager about new elements in your panel.

Here is the correct variant of your action listener:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class FrameClass extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel;

    JComboBox<String> box;

    String[] s = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

    String[] s1 = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

    public FrameClass() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        box = new JComboBox(s);
        JComboBox[] adults = new JComboBox[5];
        JComboBox[] children = new JComboBox[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            adults[i] = new JComboBox<>(s);
            children[i] = new JComboBox<>(s1);
        }

        panel.add(box, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel nested = new JPanel();
        add(nested, BorderLayout.EAST);
        box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                nested.removeAll();
                nested.setLayout(new GridLayout(box.getSelectedIndex() + 1, 2));
                for (int i = 0; i <= box.getSelectedIndex(); i++) {
                    nested.add(adults[i]);
                    nested.add(children[i]);
                }
                getContentPane().revalidate();
                getContentPane().repaint();
                pack();
            }
        });
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new FrameClass();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but new comboboxes appear only once even when the selected index is 4

Comment: @Yuriy_Puhlik You cannot add one combo box twice. You need an array of combo boxes to add.

Comment: @Yuriy_Puhlik I've changed my example. It adds now the different number of combo boxes, depending on the current selection in the main combo box.

Comment: @Yuriy_Puhlik in this case please accept my answer as correct (grey check marker) You'll get 2 points of reputation ;)